# how to find number of product for each category using sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I wish to create an sql query to list total number of film belongs to each film category. couldn't able to create any query. any help would be highly appreciated.

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| category_id | name        | last_update         |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
|           1 | Action      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           2 | Animation   | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           3 | Children    | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           4 | Classics    | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           5 | Comedy      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           6 | Documentary | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           7 | Drama       | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           8 | Family      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           9 | Foreign     | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          10 | Games       | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+

+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| film_id | category_id | last_update         |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|       1 |           6 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       2 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       3 |           6 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       4 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       5 |           8 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       6 |           9 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       7 |           5 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       8 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       9 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|      10 |          15 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a left join of `categories` to `films` so to include all categories in the results, even those with no films, and group by category to count:

```
select c.name, count(f.film_id) counter
from categories c left join films f
on f.category_id = c.category_id
group by c.category_id, c.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cGTBvE6JyPdjUcLJi63XZC/0).
Results (for your sample data which includes `category_id`s in the table `films` that don't exist in the table `categories` so they are not counted):

```
| name        | counter |
| ----------- | ------- |
| Action      | 0       |
| Animation   | 0       |
| Children    | 0       |
| Classics    | 0       |
| Comedy      | 1       |
| Documentary | 2       |
| Drama       | 0       |
| Family      | 1       |
| Foreign     | 1       |
| Games       | 0       |
```